# how to fix this errors occurs in package selenium using java?

Tags: java, selenium, netbeans

```
public class selenium {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

    }

}
```

The following errors occur

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:32)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:137)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:339)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
```

Answer (score 0):

i find answer of my question as follow 
1-first download chrome driver in the link below and save to arbitary drive like d/firefox
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads
2-
 we should set selenium to our chrome driver by setpropertycode as follow
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\Firefox\chromedriver.exe");

at the end our code hire without any error

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {      
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Firefox\\chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```